# Controlling the Transfromation Properties of a 3D Object With a Set Of Points

Tags: unity-game-engine

Allow me to elaborate, so I preprocess frames in python and extract a rectangle which roughly corresponds to the fretboard of the guitar.[image]

I then send this position information to Unity to visualize it there.
[image]

Which works charmingly, though I also want to make my 3D guitar model fit the marked dots to the dots obtained through python, meaning that it should position, scale and rotate itself according to these points.
[image]

How can I achieve this?

I am fairly new to Unity and frankly have no idea how I can achieve such a feat. Has anyone done something similar before?

Comment: rotation around the up axis will be tricky (requires perspective recognition) .. the rest should be trivial as you just align the guitars up vector with the direction of your points and can adjust the scaling using the distances ... for that 2 points would actually be enough ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Image with 5 points: X,Y are the targets; A,B are reference points on the guitar's fretboard; O is the centre of mass of the guitar]

This is the ideal setup you want. You have two points X and Y as your targets, and you have reference points A and B on the guitar. O is the location of the centre of mass

---

First, set your scale.

```cs
// dist(X,Y) = scale * dist(A,B)
float scale = Vector3.Distance(posX,posY) / Vector3.Distance(posA, posB);
transform.localScale = Vector3.Scale(baseScale, scale);
```

You must know the base (initial) scale of the guitar. This is usually `1,1,1` but in some cases (like when importing from Blender) it tends to be something like `100,100,100` so just make sure you have the right values.

---

Next, you need to rotate the guitar. We can simply modify the guitar's `transform.up`.

```
Vector3 delXY = posY - posX;
transform.up = delXY.normalized;
```

---

Finally, you need to move your guitar to the desired position. We want `A` to coincide with `X` and `B` with `Y`. Let us just solve for `A`.

```
Vector3 movementVector = posX - posA;
transform.Translate(movementVector, Space.World);
```

The guitar should now be aligned with the rectangle.

---

A few things to note:

- The variables `posX`, `posY`, `posA`, and `posB` must be in world space
- We are assuming that the rectangle is on the same plane as the front of the guitar

That's all from me. All the best for your project. I hope this helped!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your informative answer, I've just tried it out, and it works like a charm! I'm only having some problem with scaling, as it tends to scale to infinity (probably the distance is calculated as 0), but the other two (position and rotation) are as well as they could ever be. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, tanks again, I also added scaling in the x-axis too based on your reasoning.

Comment: Hi @Di0n ! Glad to hear that the solution works. All the best!